# Looking for database with ethnic information in USA

Tags: data-request, usa, machine-learning, classification

I want to train a classifier with given names or surnames of different ethnic groups available in USA. I want to know if there are any open databases available or suggestions how we can create the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voter rolls would be a fantastic place to look, the North Carolina State Board of Elections & Ethics Enforcement provides this data:

- [Voter Rolls Download](https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl.ncsbe.gov/data/ncvoter_Statewide.zip)
- [Voter Data Format](https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl.ncsbe.gov/data/ncvhis_ncvoter_data_format.txt)

The North Carolina database includes race, ethnicity, and gender. It would be a good place for your classifier to train.

Comment: There is no voter name in the field that you mentioned. I want to classify by names in to race, if the voter ID number is present I cannot use that. Instead can you provide the link to download ncvoter#.txt

Comment: @Raady I have updated the link to the one that has names.

Comment: do we have databases for other states as well ?